# How would I play these triplets?

Tags: piano, rhythm, tuplet

[image]

I’m finding it really hard to play these triplets. Also any tips on how to overall count these bars as I’m struggling to count it as a lot of the rhythm doesn’t fall on the beat and I get confused. It is hit the road jack by Ray Charles if that is any help

Comment: Find a better version. I can't even figure out if whoever wrote this did it by opening a MIDI in a notation program, or is simply musically inept.

Answer (score 13):

Oh, goodness. Please, for your own sake, find another version of this. No musician should ever have to play from something like this. It's likely this score wasn't created by a human (or at the very least, not a musician). Find another score ASAP; you're only wasting your time by trying to read this score.

As a sample of some of the notational atrocities in this example:

Measure 29 (the first measure of the second system) is best notated as:

[image]

In the next measure, there's no reason for there to be 3 sixteenth-note rests hidden under a triplet. Let's just make it:

[image]

In measure 33, the syncopation does a terrible job of showing you where every beat lies. Better would be:

[image]

(An alternative to the above, as Carl states in the comments, is to have the third beat a sixteenth followed by a dotted-eighth note. Both versions are common.)

And don't even get me started on measure 27. Why not just have the following?

[image]

---

As for your question of the triplets against an eighth-note left hand, try practicing this 3:2 rhythm with something like this:

[image]

Then add a tie to each E so that you don't rearticulate them:

[image]

Now just remove a few Ds and Cs:

[image]

And *voilà*! You're playing this rhythm; now just adjust it to match the pitches in your example.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I thought I was just awful at reading rhythm and that this version was fine

Comment: Well done -- I might prefer the Measure 33 third beat to be a sixteenth followed with a dotted eighth rather than the tie you wrote.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Good point. The fact that I debated which one to choose suggests that both are very common. I'll edit that in, thanks!